# How do I configure "appOfflineTemplate" in a publish profile (.pubxml)?

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy, pubxml

WebDeploy 3.5 supports customizing **App_Offline.html** via an *App Offline Template* option to msdeploy. Example:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:iisApp=sourceApp -dest:iisApp=destApp,appOfflineTemplate="App_offline-template.htm" -enablerule:AppOffline
```

In a publish profile I can specify **-enablerule:AppOffline** via the option

```
<EnableMSDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
```

Can I do the same with **appOfflineTemplate** ?

Reference: https://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/webdeploy-3-5-rtw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently not possible. Read more at: https://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41199-general-asp-net/suggestions/6619898-enablemsdeployappoffline-appofflinetemplate